# Synchronization blocks and the domain in which they operate

Tags: digital-communications, synchronization

I'm studying the full synchronization chain, and it's not clear to me at which domain each block works on in terms of sample vs. symbol domain. I'm particularly confused between frame synchronization and symbol timing synchronization. Coarse frequency synchronization operates on the samples, the fine frequency synchronization and PLL work on the symbols.

In the chain I'm working on, the symbol timing synchronization comes after the frame synchronization, although [here](https://pysdr.org/_images/sync-diagram.svg) the order is reversed!. My understanding is that frame synchronization relies on a synch word in the frame in the symbol domain because it has a strong peak, which means frame synchronization operates on the symbol domain as input and output. On the other hand, the symbol timing synchronization block takes as an input the samples, and outputs the symbols at the optimum sampling time. How can I reconcile these two blocks? Is the ordering wrong in my system?

Comment: I recommend reading "Introduction to Wireless Communications" by R. Heath. It has the best explanation of these issues I've seen in a textbook.